# Date in constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class with the constructor:

```
...
Date d1;
Date d2;
public DateClass(Date d1, Date d2) {
   this.d1 = d1;
   this.d2 = d2;
}
...
```

Then in another class I want to use this constructor:

```
...
DateClass d = new DateClass(what I should I write here to create Date in format mm-dd-yyyy);
System.out.println(d);
...
```

Thank you!
P.S This in not a part of a homework. I really do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a new `Date` by calling the constructor.

```
// you specify year1, month1, day1
DateClass d = new DateClass(new Date(year1-1900, month1-1, day1),
    new Date (year2-1900, month2-1, day2);
```

This is the simplest way, and will certainly work; however, as Carlos Heuberger correctly notes, this is deprecated, meaning that other ways are preferred. You can also make a new `Date` through `DateFormat`:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date d1 = df.parse("12-10-2011"); // for example, today's date
Date d2 = df.parse("01-01-1900"); // use your own dates, of course
```

To be able to print in `mm-dd-yyyy` format, implement `toString`:

```
public String toString(){
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    return "Date 1: " + df.format(d1) + " Date 2: " + df.format(d2);
}
```

Comment: 1 - the constructor is deprecated. 2 - should use `month-1`. 3 - should be `year-1900` (`2011` or just `11` would result in wrong years). All together not the best choice... (e.g `new Date(2011, 12, 10)` will be January 10th 3912; today is `new Date(111, 11, 10)`)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thanks for the suggestions! You are right on all points.

Answer (score 6):

`Date` doesn't *have* a format. It's just an instant in time, with no associated calendar or time zone. When you need to format a `Date`, you would often use a `DateFormat` which is told the calendar system to use, the time zone to convert the instant into a local time etc.

When you print out a `Date` as you're doing in the second snippet, implicitly via `toString()`, that will *always* use the system default time zone, and an unmodifiable format. (It may or may not change with system locale - I'm not sure). Basically that should *only* be used for debugging. If you want any sort of control over the text, `DateFormat` is where it's at.

If you want to be able to *simply* construct date values from year/month/day etc, I'd recommend you look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) - it's a much saner date/time API than Java's. It makes all kinds of things much cleaner, including the separation of "local time", "local date", "local date and time", "date and time in a particular time zone" etc.

Comment: I think he meant to parse a date with that format, not to create a date with that format.

Comment: @Tudor: It's basically unclear - but either way I'd suggest using Joda Time :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a SimpleDateFormat (assuming you have the two dates as strings):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date d1 = format.parse(d1String);
Date d2 = format.parse(d2String);
DateClass d = new DateClass(d1, d2);
```

Comment: I second this.  Keep in mind that [SimpleDateFormat][1] is not thread safe.

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: what id d1String? you mean if I have 08-08-94 as d1String then it works?

Comment: @user1091510 but beware, that would be year 0094, not 1994, since using `yyyy` (instead of `yy`) for the year